# Unmatched records in access table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have 2 tables and trying to pull the ECID field in table B that has different numbers when compared to table A.

Table A has the fields

```
Bas      BPN   ECID    Wt
A57890  57890  1001  5.6
CC4455  4455   1003  2.9
456778  6778   1003  8.9
345666  5666   1009  1.8
7899    7899   2030  2.7
3456    3456   3567   3.99
```

Table B has the fields

```
Bas      BPN   ECID    Wt
A57890  57890  1001  5.6
CC4455  4455   1004  2.9
456778  6778   1003  8.9
345666  5666   1011  1.8
7899    7899   2030  2.7
3456    3456   3009  3.99
```

Result looks like

```
Bas      BPN   ECID.TableA   ECID.TableB  Wt
CC4455  4455   1003            1004       2.9                        
345666  5666   1009            1011       1.8    
3456    3456   3567            3009       3.99
```

Comment: Show us your attempt, this is a pretty simple `join` with `where` criteria...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the tables match on "BAS", so that's the field you need to join. (They might need to match on "BPN" instead - cannot tell from your example. If so, use that field for the join, or use both if necessary.)  Then look for ECNs that are different.

```
SELECT A.BAS, A.BPN, A.ECID, A.Wt, B.ECID, B.Wt
FROM A INNER JOIN B ON A.BPN = B.BPN
WHERE (((B.ECID)<>[A].[ECID]));
```

This assumes you have all BAS records on both tables.  If not, you may need a union query instead.